# Excel VBA: Add Value to TextBox based on ComboBox Selection Then Sum

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating an userform that should allow me to choose an option from a combobox and I need the selection to give a textbox next to it a value because I need to perform a calculation at the end.

I have 4 Frames with 4 comboboxes each and 5 textboxes (the 5th are for the results).

I'm not sure if this is the proper approach as this is my first work with an userform.

First, I created a list with "Yes" and "No" in a sheet within the workbook and gave it a namerange. I thought it would be easier in case I need to add more values in the future without having to modify the code.

```
=OFFSET(Lists!$A$2, 0, 0, COUNTA(Lists!$A:$A),1)
```

Here's the piece of code I have so far.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim rngResponse As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Lists")

For Each rngResponse In ws.Range("Response")

Me.cbResponse1.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse2.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse3.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse4.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse5.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse6.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse7.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse8.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse9.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse10.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse11.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse12.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse13.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse14.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse15.AddItem rngResponse.Value
Me.cbResponse16.AddItem rngResponse.Value

Next rngResponse

End Sub
```

Each textbox is named as follows.

```
txtResponse1
txtResponse2
txtResponse3
txtResponse4
```

until txtResponse16

Then the textboxes were I want to display the results in each frame are

```
txtResult1
txtResult2
txtResult3
txtResult4
```

I need the "Yes" value to be worth 1 and the "No" value to be worth 0 and then SUM all the values in the frame and divide them by the count of responses. So if a cbbox is blank then the txtbox should also be blank.

Any inputs or suggestions are very much welcomed.

EDIT:

I added one of this for each comboxbox and it works but now I have 16 subs. Is there a way to shorten this?

```
Private Sub cbResponse1_Change()

If Me.cbResponse1.Value = "" Then
Me.txtResponse1.Value = ""
End If

If Me.cbResponse1.Value = "Yes" Then
Me.txtResponse1.Value = 1
End If

If Me.cbResponse1.Value = "No" Then
Me.txtResponse1.Value = 0
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cut down your code quite a bit by having one function that all the event handlers called, something like this:

```
Private Sub cbResponse1_Change()
    Call cbResponsex_Change(Me.cbResponse1, Me.txtResponse1)
End Sub

Private Sub cbResponse2_Change()
    Call cbResponsex_Change(Me.cbResponse2, Me.txtResponse2)
End Sub

Private Sub cbResponsex_Change(cbResponse As Combobox, txtResponse As TextBox)

    If cbResponse.Value = "" Then
        txtResponse.Value = ""
    End If

    If cbResponse.Value = "Yes" Then
        txtResponse.Value = 1
    End If

    If cbResponse.Value = "No" Then
        txtResponse.Value = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You Rob. However, I get an error "SubScript out of range" when I try to run this. I formatted the Change Events to match each combobox and each textbox but it seems to be a no-go for so far.

Comment: What line does the subscript out of range happen on? It can't be any of the code I suggested because it doesn't use subscripts.

Comment: I figured out that error. I was missing a sheet in the workbook I'm working on. It's the "Lists" sheet that contains that list values for Yes/No. That's fixed. Now the error I'm getting is "Type Mismatch" and it points to the first sub Private Sub cbResponse1_Change()
    Call cbResponsex_Change(Me.cbResponse1, Me.txtResponse1)
End Sub. Just as an FYI, the ComboBoxes are Text (Yes/No/Blank) and the TextBoxes should be numeric. Think it might have something to do with that? I don't have the textbox formatted. I'm still trying to figure that out in the learning process.

Comment: Change it to cbResponse As Object, txtResponse As Object. I was typing the names in from memory.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Now the values populate properly when I choose the Yes/No Options. Do you happen to know how I can SUM the values from the textboxes in each frame and divide them by the count of none-empty textboxes in that frame and time it by 100? I need to display the result as %.

I placed the textboxes on a separate frame next to the frame that contains the comboboxes. because I thought it would be more organized and easier to make the calculations.

Comment: For example. txtResponse1 to 4 are in a frame, then 5 to 8 in another frame then 9 to 12 and lastly 13 to 16. the results should be listed in txtResult1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively.

Comment: You could write some sort of for each loop which goes through your frames and then inside each frame loop through all the textboxes. Or you could just have one massive calculation like: CDbl(Frame1.TextBox1.Value) + CDbl(Frame1.TextBox2.Value) + CDbl(Frame2.TextBox1.Value)+......